# Android BroadcastReceiver Triggering Multiple Times

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

In My application, I have used a broadcast receiver for triggering some functionalities. But sometimes it's triggering 2 times.

```
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("DATA_LOST"));
```

This is called from a function inside Activity A. But while debugging I understood like that function not called 2 times. The receiver declared in Another Activity is triggered multiple times. This also not happening every time. Please see the below code.

```
  registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("DATA_LOST"));

BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)   //entered multiple times
    {
     feedbackcheck();
    }
};
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: are you unregistering your receiver with `unregisterReceiver`?

Comment: @takecare Yes tried to unregister inside the onReceive but that stopped the actions inside that function. Also tried to unregister inside onPause which cause the app to crash as well.

Comment: For future reference, the Issue resolved by closing all the  activities from background.